# Sql, firewal, port, Named Pipes Provider

Tags: php, sql, tcp, port, firewall

When I connect to the website I get Following error

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 2 [code] => 2 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0] 
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. 
[message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ) 
[1] => Array
( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 
[2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 
[1] => 2 [code] => 2 
[2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )
```

I connect from an Application Server PHP to a Database Server with the following settings

```
$serverName = "tcp:161.202.147.54\DZUHE00219,2311"; 
        $myUser = "CHAD\myLoging"; 
        $myPass = "MyPassword"; 
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"zentraleDatenbank", "UID"=>$myUser, "PWD"=>$myPass);
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

I tried diffrent options with the Servername. With tcp, without tcp, Servername. Nothing helped.

First I was thinking this could be a problem with the firewall. The firewall isn't active. Second I thought it coult be the Port. But I can connect from the Application Server with Visual Studio to the DB with the exact same cridentials.

does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: is there a reason you have an undefined variable `$serverName`? Should this be `$myServer` instead?

Comment: oh. I tried diffrend things and this is a copy and paste mistake. but the problem is still there

Comment: Does someone have any idea?

Comment: have you tried just putting the IP address alone? `161.202.147.54` or alternatively (assuming the port number is correct - default is 1433) `161.202.147.54, 2311`. Also - is the server that you are executing the php script on the same server that your database is installed on?